# How to localize SharePoint publishing page title

Tags: c#, localization, sharepoint-2010

How does one localize the page title of a SharePoint publishing page? I am provisioning it like:

```
PublishingPage newPage = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add("mypage.aspx", "mylayout.aspx");
newPage.Title = "$Resources:MYRESX,MyPage_PageTitle";
newPage.Update();
```

When I provision this page, the title shows up literally, `$Resources:MYRESX,MyPage_PageTitle`, instead of SharePoint looking up the string. So, I guess my assumption is wrong that SharePoint would look the string up. Or I have the syntax wrong.

I am already referencing `MYRESX` in other places; I am sure the resource file / string is accessible.

---

I have the exact same issue for webpart titles as well, so hopefully a unified solution exists for both scenarios.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [SPUtility.GetLocalizedString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx):

```
newPage.Title = 
    SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(
        "$Resources:MyPage_PageTitle", 
        "MYRESX", 
        web.Language);
```

Comment: This is correct, but actually in my scenario I realized that I am just being dumb. I am using site variations for localization with publishing pages, and in my case I should just edit the page in the variation site and set the title there. I'm accepting as answer but note that this code should be run at runtime, not an provision-time, so the title is dynamically grabbed for the user's specified culture.